# How to disable redmi note 7 recommended apps

Tags: applications, disable-app

Since one of the last updates, my phone has started showing me recommended apps when opening a folder on my screen.

How do I disable such behavior?

I tried following some guides online involving privacy settings, but it didn't help!

Apps recommendation:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as the "more apps folder promoted apps issue"

1. Open the More Apps folder (in your case Giochi?)
2. Tap on the folder name ‘More Apps’ or whatever you renamed it (tap on the Giochi as seen on the screenhot you provided)
3. Turn off the Promoted apps switch.

Comment: I had no idea that option was there, it must be a rather new one, because it wasn't there when I created the folder; I have finally disabled it, thanks.